# Python creating two dictionaries, matching keys and print value

Tags: python, dictionary, compare, key

How do I take information from one dictionary to look up the associated name in another dictionary?  For example, one dictionary I create contains the name, email address, and id of all users in a system.  The other dictionary contains just an id.

I want to take the id from a transcript and look to see which user wrote the transcript.  The id is a numerical string

Here is what I have, but all it returns the same user name regardless of the transcript_id number I enter.

```
transcript = transcript.find(id=transcript_id)

for admin in category.all():
    user = {'name': admin.name, 'id': admin.id, 'email': admin.email }

for part in transcript.transcript_parts:
    transcript_author = { 'id': part.author.id }

for key in transcript_author:
        if key in user:
            print(user['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for presence in a dict (`if key in user`) looks only in the keys of the dict which is not what you want. You want to compare the value, specifically of the `'id'` key.

Consider this:

```
>>> user = {'name': 'chrism1148', 'id': '12345', 'email': None}
>>> '12345' in user
False # fails as '12345' is not one of the keys
>>> 'id' in user
True # succeeds as 'id' is a key
>>> '12345' == user['id']
True # this works, but will throw an exception if 'id' is not in the dict for some reason
>>> '12345' == user.get('id', None)
True # it's a good idea to use this instead (None is used as a default value for when 'id' is not present in the dict)
```